# Most efficient way to check 3 lists for a common integer in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have 3 lists of type `::[Integer]` , which are sorted from smallest to largest ,all of arbitrary and different lengths, what would be the most efficient way to find all common integers, if any exist, in all 3 lists.

Comment: Just as a note, `[Integer]` is not an *array* of integers, but a *list* of integers.  There is a **very** big difference between lists and arrays.

Comment: @Ptharien'sFlame ah thanks for the correction i'll update my question, and your right it does

Comment: I would go with Data.List.sort and than two Data.List.Ordered.isect

Comment: link for kyticka's suggestion: [Data.List.Ordered.isect](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/data-ordlist/latest/doc/html/Data-List-Ordered.html#v:isect)

Comment: [profiling supports using isect](https://s3.amazonaws.com/jd2-4a7cb8e3affb4a7f0cf8229a481d0dc3-us/public/ProfileIntersect.html) ([source](https://gist.github.com/rampion/5938169))

Comment: @rampion: +1 for actually profiling it. You should use `S.fromAscList` and `IS.fromAscList` instead of `S.fromList` and `IS.fromList` though - the `fromAscList` functions are more efficient but expect that the input is sorted.

Comment: Frerich Raabe: I tried that too, didn't go to the trouble of posting it. It improved the performance of `Data.Set` by a factor of 2, but didn't really change the performance of `Data.IntSet`.

Comment: @rampion any links to learn more about profiling like you did? and hosting it on amazon was really neat

Comment: @pyCthon: Judging from the footer of the HTML report, the profiling was done by [Criterion](http://www.serpentine.com/blog/2009/09/29/criterion-a-new-benchmarking-library-for-haskell/).

Comment: @FrerichRaabe yeah your right thanks! it's in his source too from the gist too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if this is the fastest but should be pretty fast.  Uses the fact that the lists or ordered.

```
repeats :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
repeats [] _ _    = []
repeats _ [] _    = []
repeats _ _  []   = []
repeats a@(x:xs) b@(y:ys) c@(z:zs)
   | x == y && y == z     = x : repeats xs ys zs
   | x <= y && x <= z     = repeats xs b c
   | y <= x && y <= z     = repeats a ys c
   | otherwise            = repeats a b zs
```

If the first element of all the lists is the same then we add that to the list of repeats.  Otherwise we discard the least value of any of the lists are then recurse.  If you had n lists you would probably need a binary heap or something.

**EDIT**

tail recursive version

```
repeatsTail :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
repeatsTail f s t = go f s t []
   where go [] _ _  acc = reverse acc 
         go  _ [] _ acc = reverse acc 
         go  _ _ [] acc = reverse acc 
         go a@(x:xs) b@(y:ys) c@(z:zs) acc 
            | x == y && y == z     = go xs ys zs (x:acc)
            | x <= y && x <= z     = go xs b c acc 
            | y <= x && y <= z     = go a ys c acc 
            | otherwise            = go a b zs acc
```

EDIT 2:

With as patterns

Comment: +1: This seems to be about 30% faster than my IntSet-based solution for a pretty random data set (finding common numbers in [1..100000], [50000..150000] and [20000..60000]). Small suggestion: you could use as-patterns here to avoid constructing the lists again, i.e. `repeats a@(x:xs) b@(y:ys) c@(z:zs)` and then you could have e.g. `repeats a b zs` in your `otherwise` branch.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe I added them.  When i was writing it I didn't know what i would call them. :-P Feel free to edit my posts in the future.

Comment: If you put the triple-cons case first, you only need 1 base case, not 3.

Comment: I prefer the version that is not tail recursive.  It will work incrementally and with infinite lists.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe `*Main> length $ intersection3 [1..100000] [50000..150000] [20000..60000] => 10001 (0.27 secs, 30790752 bytes)` 
`*Main> length $ repeats [1..100000] [50000..150000] [20000..60000] => 10001 (0.53 secs, 23823260 bytes)`

Comment: @groovy: Hm, I tested it with ghc 7.6.3 passing just `-O2` on the command line (and I compared it to the first `repeats` version, which is not tail recursive).

Comment: Tail recursion will not buy you anything here. The non tail-recursive version might even be faster.

Comment: @is7s it was more for space usage with really large lists.

Comment: @DiegoNolan even from this aspect I believe the guarded-recursion version is better.

Answer (score 7):

- The **most concise way** would probably be to use the function Data.List.intersect:

  ```
  import Data.List (intersect)

  intersect [1, 2, 3] (intersect [1, 2] [2, 3])
  ```

  The problem with this solution is that `intersect` has to traverse the lists more than once in order to find matching elements.
- If you want to avoid this overhead, you have to store the elements in a more efficient data structure, at least temporarily. The obvious and probably **reasonably efficient** solution would be to convert to sets and use Data.Set.intersection:

  ```
  import Data.Set (fromList, toList, intersection)

  toList (intersection (fromList [1, 2, 3]) (intersection (fromList [1, 2]) (fromList [2, 3])))
  ```
- If the elements of the list are small enough to fit into `Int` (instead of `Integer`), you could use `Data.IntSet` instead of `Data.Set` to **improve the performance**:

  ```
  import Data.IntSet (fromList, toList, intersection)

  toList (intersection (fromList [1, 2, 3]) (intersection (fromList [1, 2]) (fromList [2, 3])))
  ```
- If you need more performance, you have to **choose a data structure** that is appropriate for the numbers in your lists. Maybe [bitsets](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bitset) work for your use case? Or you could try to use `UArray Int Boolean` with the `accumArray` function somehow.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Data.List.intersection; you could make the Data.Set/Data.IntSet solutions more efficient by using `fromAscList` instead of `fromList` since you know that the input is sorted.

Answer (score 3):

For short lists, I would simply build something using [`elem`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3aelem). You could maybe exploit the insight that any number which appears in all three lists has to appear in the shortest list: so you only need to consider all numbers in the shortest list.

For longer lists, I'd convert the lists to [`IntSet`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-IntSet.html#t%3aIntSet) and then use [`intersection`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-IntSet.html#v%3aintersection):

```
import Data.IntSet

intersection3 :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
intersection3 a b c = toList $ fromAscList a `intersection` fromAscList b `intersection` fromAscList c
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work pretty fast too:

```
import Data.List (sort,group)

f a b c = map head
        . filter (not . null . drop 2) 
        . group
        . sort 
        $ a ++ b ++ c
```

Comment: Without trying, I suspect that it breaks if one of the list contains duplicates, e.g. consider `[1,1,2]`, `[1,2]` and `[2,3]`.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe good point. As is, it breaks down if the list contains duplicates.